# print the index of the character where it is out of alphabetical order

Tags: java

I am having trouble understanding an interview question, I am meant to print out the index of the character where it is out of alphabetical order. I do not know how to ascertain the index of a character where it is out of alphabetical order. I wrote the full question below:

Write an algorithm to check if a string is sorted in alphabetical order and print O If it is, if it is not in alphabetical order, then print the index of the character where it is out of alphabetical order.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
 
public class ArrayAlphabet {
 

    static boolean isAlphabaticOrder(String s)
    {
        // length of the string
        int n = s.length();
       
        // create a character array
        // of the length of the string
        char c[] = new char [n];
       
        // assign the string
        // to character array
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            c[i] = s.charAt(i);
        }
       
        // sort the character array
        Arrays.sort(c);
       
        // check if the character array
        // is equal to the string or not
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            if (c[i] != s.charAt(i)) 
                return false;
               
        return true;    
    }
}


public class Main extends ArrayAlphabet {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
    
        
        String s = "aadbbbcc";
         
        // check whether the string is
        // in alphabetical order or not
        if (isAlphabaticOrder(s))
           System.out.println("0");
        else
            System.out.println("No");
           
    }
}
```

Comment: A `String` is an array of `char`s, so you can walk over the chars and compare the current `char` with the `char` you read before

Answer (score 2):

The code in the original question already uses `char charAt(int index)` of the [`String` API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html).  So, step through the String, and use `charAt` to compare each character to the preceding one.

```
 public int findOutOfOrder (String str) {
    // returns 0 if characters of str are in order.
    // if not in order, returns position of first out of order character

    int r = 0;

    for (int i = 1; i < str.length(); ++i) {
        if (str.charAt(i) < str.charAt(i - 1)) {
           r = i;
           break;
        }
    }
    return r;
 }
```

Since the requirement is to return an index, the return type should be `int`.

Comment: You could/should eliminate the variable `r`.

Comment: Thanks for the source code correction. My preference for introducing the extra variable, `r` comes from my history: My first language was FORTRAN IV, where we couldn't rely on the value of a loop index variable outside the range of the loop. Also, one place where I used to work, we were asked to not have a `return` inside the body of a loop.

Comment: yeah it's definitely a style thing, and therefore a religious debate (ie no right answer). Trying not to preach, I lean towards two separate return statements that correspond to the two types of results (in loop, after loop) and makes it clearer what happens when no early condition is found by returning a constant (eg `return 0;`), which is much more obvious than having to figure out what happens by reading everything from the declaration of `r`, to see what the "default" return value is, onwards to see what might have happened to it between declaration and the return.

Answer (score 1):

As you traverse the string index by index, you can keep a track of the largest character seen so far. If at any point, you see a character which is lower than seen before, you can return that index.

e.g.

```
01234
acfbg

start by highest seen = a

index = 0, char = a, highest seen = a, a < a? no. [highest seen = a]
index = 1, char = c, highest seen = a, c < a? no. [highest seen = c]
index = 2, char = f, highest seen = c, f < c? no. [highest seen = f]
index = 3, char = b, highest seen = f, b < f? yes [return index 3]
```

If you are able to traverse the entire string without finding a violation, that means the string is in alphabetical order.

Time complexity is `O(length of string)`. Space complexity is `O(1)`

Comment: You don't need to record or even know "the highest seen so far". You only need to find where char at i + 1 < char at i.